# Em qual ordem o event loop processa callbacks assíncronos?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou estudando sobre assíncronismo no Javascript, mais especificamente o comportamento no NodeJs.

Em vários artigos, li que a ordem que o event loop processa os "eventos/callbacks" é seguindo o *FIFO* *(first-in, first out)* e até pouco tempo pensava que realmente era assim, pois já havia feito alguns testes com funções `setTimeout` com tempo zerado, por exemplo:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 0)
setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 0)
setTimeout(() => console.log(3), 0)
```

e a ordem de retorno sempre era "respeitada", mas depois de testar um trecho de código que vi em um livro fiquei um pouco confuso sobre esta ordem.

trecho de exemplo:

```
const http = require('http')

http.get('http://stackoverflow.com/', function(response) {
    console.log('FIRST CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP')
})

http.get('http://olx.com.br/', function(response) {
    console.log('SECOND CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP')
})

http.get('http://nubank.com.br/', function(response) {
    console.log('THIRD CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP')
})
```

O comportamento que eu esperava é que fosse exibido `FIRST CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP`, `SECOND CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP`, `THIRD CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP` de acordo com a ordem que foram enviados ao event loop, independente do tempo que cada request demore para completar.

Só que o retorno é "dinâmico", e algumas vezes recebi:

```
THIRD CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP
SECOND CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP
FIRST CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP
```

e outras

```
SECOND CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP
THIRD CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP
FIRST CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP
```

mas nunca o `FIRST CALLBACK INTO EVENT LOOP` foi o primeiro retorno.

OBS: as URLs dos requests de exemplo foram escolhidas de próposito pois imaginei que o servidor/dns do `stackoverflow.com` estaria mais distante que os da `olx.com.br` e `nubank.com` para verificar que a ordem de execução iria ser mantida mesmo com requests mais demorados

Tenho noção que a engine do Javascript depende do "hospedeiro" para executar suas tarefas, e no caso do request, o sistema operacional que fica responsável de notificar o event loop para executar o callback quando o response está pronto

Dito tudo isso, o event loop processa os eventos por ordem de chegada ou quem completa primeiro? existe diferença para eventos que dependem de rede, I/O?

Por que o `setTimeout` "respeita" a ordem e o request http do exemplo não?

Comment: O motivo é porque **não existe "fila"**, você é livre para controlar (ou não) isso e por isso o `setTimeout` é executado dessa forma (no seu exemplo, saída pode variar). A lib `http` não tem controle de fila e também vai processar conforme receber a resposta primeiro de quem processar a requisição e resposta HTTP primeiro (o que depende do servidor HTTP e não do front). Você pode criar uma fila própria e determinar o "quando" e "como". É uma pergunta que já tem bastante respostas no site, dá uma olhada nos links.

Answer (score 2):

Quando o *callback* está pronto para ser executado, cria-se uma fila, que como consta na própria pergunta é executada de modo FIFO (*first in, first out*).

Mas repare que essa fila só executa os *callbacks* que estão *prontos* para serem executados. Ou seja, executar as operações assíncronas que foram finalizadas.

Claro, se você chamar três funções assíncronas, `A`, `B` e `C` que levam o mesmo tempo para terminar, a ordem de execução do *callback*, naturalmente, será `A`, `B`, `C`.

No entanto, se `B` terminar primeiro, ele entrará na fila antes que, por exemplo, `A`.

Isso pode ser facilmente testado *mudando* o tempo de cada `setTimeout`:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('A');
}, 300);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('B');
}, 100);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('C');
}, 200);
```

Veja que a ordem de impressão é `BCA` porque o primeiro *callback* a ser executado é o `B`. Ele foi o primeiro a entrar na fila. Depois, `C` e, por fim, `A`.

Não faz sentido esperar mais só para fazer jus à órdem na qual os *callbacks* foram criados. Isso iria contra o objetivo primário do assincronismo em JavaScript, que é não bloquear a (única) *thread* desnecessariamente. Enquanto alguma coisa não termina, tem outra sendo feita. :)

Veja mais [aqui](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Portanto, o `setTimeout`, tal como no exemplo do AP, “respeita a ordem do código” haja vista que têm o mesmo tempo de resolução. As requisições HTTP, todavia, podem demorar diferentes intervalos de tempo, de modo a alterar a ordem de execução dos *callbacks* em relação ao código.